# Counting the number of leaves in a tree

Tags: haskell, tree

Using Haskell, I'm writing a function that counts the total number of leaves in a tree. I have defined the tree as so:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

I writing a function that does this by:

```
countL :: Tree a -> Int
countL Leaf = 1
countL (Node x tL tR) = (countL tL) + (countL tR)
```

This works but I want to take it a step further by doing the same thing using the fold function. I've having a working fold function for trees that I defined by doing:

```
mytFold :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
mytFold f g Leaf = g
mytFold f g (Node a xl xr) = f a (mytFold f g xl) (mytFold f g xr)
```

I tried to include the fold function (also used a helper function that I defined by doing this:

```
countL' :: Tree a -> Integer
countL' Leaf = 1
countL' = mytFold leafy 0 where
        leafy tL tR = tL + tR
```

But I'm getting some weird errors. Does anyone have any insight on what's wrong?

Comment: @dbaupp I'm getting "Equations for `countL'' have different numbers of arguments

Comment: And indeed you see that `countL` has different numbers of arguments in the two equations. Just change the third line to `countL' t = mytFold leafy 0 t where`
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two syntactic/type problems. Firstly, every top level binding must have the same number of arguments, so

```
countL' Leaf = ..
countL' = ..
```

isn't valid. One solution is

```
countL' Leaf = ..
countL' tree = mytFold leafy 0 tree
```

Once you've done this, then GHC gives you an error like

```
    Couldn't match expected type `Integer -> Integer'
                with actual type `Integer'
    Expected type: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
      Actual type: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
    In the first argument of `mytFold', namely `leafy'
    In the expression: mytFold leafy 0 tree
```

Which is because `mytFold` requires a 3-argument function as its first argument, and `leafy` just takes 2. Fix this by using `leafy _ tL tR = tL + tR`.

---

However, once you have done this, you will see that this gives the wrong answer: `countL' (Node 1 Leaf Leaf) == 0`. A way that might make the solution clear is to removing the `countL' Leaf` case, and trying to write `countL` as just the fold. i.e.

```
countL'' = mytFold f a
```

where you have do decide what `f` and `a` are (hint: you already have `f == leafy == const (+)`). Consider `mytFold leafy a Leaf`.